# How to view asp.net mvc3 web app from iphone or android browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm testing a mvc web app on local PC, I would like to view the localhost web pages from a mobile device so that i can test my jquery mobile script on swipe gesture.

Any idea how can I run a simulator or use third party tools to do that?

Comment: This will give you all you need to know: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimulatingAnIPhoneOrIPadBrowserForASPNETMobileWebDevelopmentWithWebMatrix2OrVisualStudio2012.aspx :)